# Python3 search by value in nested dictionaries and lists then get other nearest keys/values pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'targets': [{'hosts': ['google.fr'],
              'tags': {'country': 'fr',
                       'server': 'french'}},
             {'hosts': ['amazon.es'],
              'tags': {'country': 'es',
                       'server': 'spain'}},
             {'hosts': ['facebook.de'],
              'tags': {'country': 'de',
                       'server': 'germany'}},
             {'hosts': ['server1.fr', 'server2.fr', 'server3.fr'],
              'tags': {'country': 'fr',
                       'server': 'french'}}]}
```

Basically a dictionary with nested lists, dictionaries, and strings, of arbitrary depth.

What is the best way of traversing this to extract the nearest key 'tags' where 'host' equal to my search ?

My attempt:

```
#host = 'google.fr' or 'amazon.es' or 'facebook.de' or 'server1.fr' or 'server2.fr' or 'server3.fr'

for [idx, val] in enumerate(targets['targets']):
    h = targets['targets'][idx]['hosts']
    for i in h:
        if i == host and 'tags' in targets['targets'][idx]: # if equal to host and 'tags' key exist
            t = targets['targets'][idx]['tags']

            tags = ','.join("{!s}={!r}".format(key,val) for (key,val) in t.items())
            tags = tags.replace("'", "")

            pprint ("host: '{}'".format(host))
            pprint("tags: '{}'".format(tags))
```

Result:

```
"host: 'google.fr'"
"tags: 'country=fr,server=french'"
"host: 'amazon.es'"
"tags: 'country=es,server=spain'"
"host: 'facebook.de'"
"host: 'server1.fr'"
"tags: 'country=fr,server=french'"
"host: 'server2.fr'"
"tags: 'country=fr,server=french'"
"host: 'server3.fr'"
"tags: 'country=fr,server=french'"
```

I'm not a python expert and I'm sure it's possible to have better performance.

Benchmark:

```
        wwii        azro

real    0m0,087s    0m0,057s
user    0m0,071s    0m0,027s
sys     0m0,015s    0m0,028s

real    0m0,078s    0m0,067s
user    0m0,068s    0m0,056s
sys     0m0,009s    0m0,010s

real    0m0,074s    0m0,058s
user    0m0,062s    0m0,024s
sys     0m0,011s    0m0,034s
```

Looks like azro's performing better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the indexed-iteration and look for host inclusion rather than equality

```
host = "google.fr"
for target in targets['targets']:
    if host in target['hosts'] and 'tags' in target:
        tags = ','.join("{!s}={!r}".format(key, val) for (key, val) in target['tags'].items())
        tags = tags.replace("'", "")
        print("host: '{}'".format(host))
        print("tags: '{}'".format(tags))
```

Comment: I just tried your code and I'm getting better performance, good job, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the dictionary is `d`:

```
import operator
hosts = operator.itemgetter('hosts')
tags = operator.itemgetter('tags')
fmt = 'country={country},server={server}'
space = d['targets']

term = 'google.fr'
# filter
items = (item for item in space if term in hosts(item))
for item in items:
    print(f'host:{term}')
    print(fmt.format(**tags(item)))
    # or
    print(','.join(f'{key}={value}' for key,value in tags(item).items()))
```

Comment: good approch, but with `fmt` to preconfigure this is not dynamic in the sense that the tags change "country" or "server" by "zipcode" I couldn't get them back or if user add another tag

Comment: Thank you wwii for this update, it seems that azro has a better performance ;)